# Result of call to function returning Bool is unused

Tags: swift, xcode, uiprintinteractioncntrler, xcode14

Just updated to XCode 14 this morning and am receiving this strange warning

**Result of call to function returning 'Bool' is unused**

when working with the present function for printing via AirPrint. This was not an issue in XCode 13 and I cannot see any reason it's happening now, except if something changed in Swift 6.

Hoping someone knows the answer.

Here's the function:

```
/// Prints the PDF file using airprint
        func printPDF() {
            let pdfFileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(
                "Filename.pdf"
            )
            let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
            let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)

            printInfo.jobName = "Print PDF"
            printInfo.outputType = .general

            printController.printInfo = printInfo
            printController.printingItem = pdfFileURL
            printController.present(animated: true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in // <-- Result of call to function returning 'Bool' is unused
                if error == nil {
                    if isPrinted {
                        print("Print Success")
                    } else {
                        print("Print Failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Error")")
                    }
                }
            }
        } // End Func
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprintinteractioncontroller) the signature of the function is:

```
func present(animated: Bool, completionHandler: UIPrintInteractionController.CompletionHandler?) -> Bool
```

if you don´t need the returned value use:

```
let _ = printController.present(animated: true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in
```